Rules for Custom MatCap dimensions?
Made a few custom MatCaps 512 x 512px imported into blender, some look ok, most look blurry or pixelated. What are some rules for creating HQ Custom MatCaps for use in blender 4.1? (dimension limit, ppi, etc.)
